# Column 'field' in field list is ambiguous in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

```
INSERT INTO  users (phone, no_of_coupon) 
SELECT couponentries.phone, 1
FROM couponentries LEFT JOIN users ON couponentries.phone = 
users.phone
WHERE users.phone IS NULL
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users.no_of_coupon = users.no_of_coupon + 1;
```

I am trying to input date in the couponentries table and then it will automatically insert only the phone numbers into users table. If there is a duplicate phone number, no_of_coupon will increment by 1. But when I executed this code in the phpmyadmin trigger [trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqIO1.png), it has an error below. Could someone help me please? Thanks

> Could not able to execute Column 'users.no_of_coupon' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Is `no_of_coupon` part of the primary key on the `users` table?

Comment: no_of_coupon is not a primary key on users table. Phone is the primary key

Comment: If so then what's the essence of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users.no_of_coupon = users.no_of_coupon + 1;`

Comment: @cdaiga I wanna increment the count of coupon related to the phone number by `no_of_coupon`, so if there are same `phone` again, `no_of_coupon` add 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an alias to users table used in join clause

```
INSERT INTO  users (phone, no_of_coupon) 
SELECT c.phone, 1
FROM couponentries c 
LEFT JOIN users u ON c.phone = u.phone
WHERE u.phone IS NULL
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users.no_of_coupon = users.no_of_coupon + 1;
```

I guess you don't need the join part you can just use

```
INSERT INTO users (phone) 
SELECT c.phone
FROM couponentries c 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE no_of_coupon = no_of_coupon + 1;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/YHUB55976)

Comment: Hi thank you the error is gone now. But I have another question, in this way if I enter the coupon with same phone number again it won't increment the `no_of_coupon` by 1. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: @BartonDong because your select query isn't returning any records

Comment: Thank you again for putting so much effort! I used this way before but since I am inserting from an outside webform so each time I entered a new coupon the no_of_coupon will count everything, for example, if I entered three coupons with the same phone number, in the end, it will be 5(0 + 2 + 3). Could you please help me again?